# Как исправить ошибку в шаблоне smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знаком со smarty , где засела ошибка, не регистрируются пользователи на сайте

```
*5083336 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template &quot;db:avtor_new_reg.tpl&quot;  on line 50 &quot;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Вы успешно зарегистрировались на сайте {$ f.site_name} .&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&quot;  - Unexpected &quot; &quot;, expected one of: &quot;{&quot; , &quot;identifier&quot;' in /var/www/html/site.ru/include/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:657
```

Comment: Ошибка в шаблоне "avtor_new_reg.tpl", не благодари.

Comment: `{$ f.site_name}`  если все именно так, то, очевидно, пробел следует убрать.

Comment: Большое спасибо, вопрос решен, да, ошибка в пробеле была {$ f.site_name}